# Open search result in new window

Tags: javascript, php, html

How to open search result on new window. what is the problem in this code.
It opens the new tab but not processing the results

```
<form action="hhtp://google.com/search" method = "get" target="_blank">
<input type ="text" name="q"/>

<input type ="submit" value = "search>
</form>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to send the GET to google? Or is google just a placeholder?

Comment: Why are there stars around the form?  Also - you specified hhtp instead of http in your url, and you have lots of additional spaces around your = signs.  I think Google probably wants you to use https; and maybe a post instead of a get, but if you look at the source of their search page, you can probably find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your `action` attribute (hhtp instead of http)

**Answer:**
Thank you [@zws's JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/khggyLrf/) in the comment HAS the answer.

```
<form action="http://google.com/search" method="get" target="_blank">
  <input type="text" name="q">
  <input type="submit" value="search">
</form>
```

**EDIT 1:**
If you want to perform a web search it is recommended to use
[Google's custom search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/)

**EDIT 2:**
You might get the idea to use AJAX to perform a POST or GET to Google's search form/page but that won't work either because of CSRF ([Cross Site Request Forgery](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet))

Comment: then what would be the right code?

Comment: @AliUppal Unfortunately I'm no expert in this matter but I've updated the answer with a link to Google's search API.

Comment: thanks for helping me :)

Comment: @AliUppal It's most likely your first question, so if you are satisfied with the answer, accept it ;)

Comment: `target="_blank" only works with anchor <a> tags` http://jsfiddle.net/khggyLrf/ It opens fine for me in a new window.